# BlackJack in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular.js, playing-cards

I wrote the following code in Angular as to accomplish a technical test for a UK job. My impression was that it is very neat and well object oriented. To my big surprise, they rejected it. Could someone find any problematic points as to ameliorate my coding performance?

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).
   controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      var Deck=['C10','D10','H10','S10','C2','D2','H2','S2','C3','D3','H3','S3','C4','D4','H4','S4','C5','D5','H5','S5','C6','D6','H6','S6',
   'C7','D7','H7','S7','C8','D8','H8','S8','C9','D9','H9','S9','CA','DA','HA','SA','CJ','DJ','HJ','SJ','CK','DK','HK','SK','CQ','DQ','HQ','SQ'];
      $scope.finalMessage='';
   
      function blackJackGame(){
    this.Deck=shuffle(Deck);
       this.dealer=new Player('dealer');
    this.player=new Player('player'); 
   }
   
   function Player(name){
    this.name=name;
       this.score=[0,0];
    this.aces=0;
    this.cards=[]; 
   }
   
   Player.prototype.Hit=function(value,arr){
    self=this;
    this.cards.push(arr[value]);
       if (arr[value].slice(1)==='J' || arr[value].slice(1)==='K' || arr[value].slice(1)==='Q') {
     this.score[0]+=10;
     this.score[1]+=10;
     calculate(self);
    }    
    else if (arr[value].slice(1)==='A') {
     this.aces++;
     if (this.aces>1) {
      this.score[0]++;
      this.score[1]++;
     }
     else { 
      this.score[0]++;
      this.score[1]+=11;
     }
        calculate(self);
    }
    else {
     this.score[0]+=parseInt(arr[value].slice(1));
     this.score[1]+=parseInt(arr[value].slice(1));+
        calculate(self);
    }    
   };   //end of Player.prototype.Hit
   
   function calculate(self){
      if (self.name==='player') {
     if (self.score[0]===self.score[1]) {
       $scope.playerScore=self.score[0];
       $scope.playerCards=self.cards;
     }
     else {
      if (self.score[1]<=21) {
        $scope.playerScore=self.score[0]+'/'+self.score[1];
        $scope.playerCards=self.cards;
      }
      else {
        self.score[1]=self.score[0];  
        $scope.playerScore=self.score[0];
        $scope.playerCards=self.cards; 
      }
     }
      }
      if (self.name==='dealer') {
     if (self.score[0]===self.score[1]) {
       $scope.dealerScore=self.score[0];
       $scope.dealerCards=self.cards;
     }
     else {
      if (self.score[1]<=21) {  
        $scope.dealerScore=self.score[0]+'/'+self.score[1];
        $scope.dealerCards=self.cards;
      }
      else {
        self.score[1]=self.score[0];
        $scope.dealerScore=self.score[0];
        $scope.dealerCards=self.cards; 
      }
     } 
      }
   }    //end of calculate
   
   $scope.startNewGame=function (){
    $scope.finalMessage='';
    var counter=3;
    var Game=new blackJackGame();
    Game.player.Hit(0,Game.Deck);
    Game.dealer.Hit(1,Game.Deck);
    Game.player.Hit(2,Game.Deck);
    $scope.enableButtons=true; 
     
    $scope.hitButton=function (){
     Game.player.Hit(counter,Game.Deck);
     if (Game.player.score[0]>21){
      $scope.finalMessage="PLAYER LOSES";
      $scope.enableButtons=false;
     }
     else
       counter++;
    };
    
    $scope.stickButton=function (){
     $scope.enableButtons=false;
     $scope.playerScore=Game.player.score[1];
     while (Game.dealer.score[1]<17){
         Game.dealer.Hit(counter,Game.Deck);
      counter++;
     }
     $scope.dealerScore=Game.dealer.score[1];
        if ($scope.dealerScore>21){
      $scope.finalMessage="PLAYER WINS";
     }
     else if ($scope.dealerScore>$scope.playerScore){
      $scope.finalMessage="PLAYER LOSES";
     }
     else if ($scope.dealerScore<$scope.playerScore){
      $scope.finalMessage="PLAYER WINS";
     }
     else {
      $scope.finalMessage="DRAW";
     }
       };
   };  //end of $scope.startNewGame
   }]);
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.card {
 width: 120px;
 height: 174px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 10px;
 margin: 2px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.cards {
 min-height: 210px;
}

.C10 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') 0px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D10 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -120px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H10 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -240px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S10 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -360px 0px no-repeat;
}
.C2 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -480px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D2 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -600px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H2 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -720px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S2 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -840px 0px no-repeat;
}
.C3 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -960px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D3 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -1080px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H3 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -1200px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S3 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -1320px 0px no-repeat;
}
.C4 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -1440px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D4 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -1560px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H4 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -1680px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S4 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -1800px 0px no-repeat;
}
.C5 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -1920px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D5 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -2040px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H5 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -2160px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S5 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -2280px 0px no-repeat;
}
.C6 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -2400px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D6 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -2520px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H6 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -2640px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S6 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -2760px 0px no-repeat;
}
.C7 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -2880px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D7 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3000px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H7 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3120px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S7 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3240px 0px no-repeat;
}
.C8 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3360px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D8 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3480px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H8 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3600px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S8 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3720px 0px no-repeat;
}
.C9 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3840px 0px no-repeat;
}
.D9 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -3960px 0px no-repeat;
}
.H9 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -4080px 0px no-repeat;
}
.S9 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -4200px 0px no-repeat;
}
.CA {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -4320px 0px no-repeat;
}
.DA {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -4440px 0px no-repeat;
}
.HA {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -4560px 0px no-repeat;
}
.SA {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -4680px 0px no-repeat;
}
.CJ {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -4800px 0px no-repeat;
}
.DJ {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -4920px 0px no-repeat;
}
.HJ {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -5040px 0px no-repeat;
}
.SJ {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -5160px 0px no-repeat;
}
.Joker1 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -5280px 0px no-repeat;
}
.Joker2 {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -5400px 0px no-repeat;
}
.CK {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -5520px 0px no-repeat;
}
.DK {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -5640px 0px no-repeat;
}
.HK {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -5760px 0px no-repeat;
}
.SK {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -5880px 0px no-repeat;
}
.CQ {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -6000px 0px no-repeat;
}
.DQ {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -6120px 0px no-repeat;
}
.HQ {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -6240px 0px no-repeat;
}
.SQ {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CPtk.png') -6360px 0px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Blackjack</title>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blackjack.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
   window.shuffle = function (set) {
    var length = set.length;
    var shuffled = new Array(length);
    for (var index = 0, rand; index < length; index++) {
     rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (index + 1));
     if (rand !== index) shuffled[index] = shuffled[rand];
     shuffled[rand] = set[index];
    }
    return shuffled;
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Blackjack</a>
     </div>
     <div class="navbar-collapse">
      <button type="button" ng-click="startNewGame()" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn new-game">New Game</button>
     </div>
    </nav>
   </div>
   <!--
   template(s) for result banner
   <div class="result alert alert-warning">PLAYER LOSES</div>
   -->
            <div ng-if="finalMessage!==''" class="result alert" ng-class="{'alert-danger':finalMessage==='PLAYER LOSES',
            'alert-info':finalMessage==='DRAW','alert-success':finalMessage==='PLAYER WINS'} ">{{finalMessage}}</div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
     <div class="dealer panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Dealer
       <div class="pull-right">
        <span>Score:</span>
        <span class="score">{{dealerScore}}</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cards panel-body">
       <!--
       template for a card
       <div class="card DQ"></div>
       -->
                            <div class="card" ng-repeat="card in dealerCards" ng-class="dealerCards[$index]"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
     <div class="player panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Player
       <div class="pull-right">
        <span>Score:</span>
        <span class="score">{{playerScore}}</span>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="cards panel-body">
       <!--
       template for a card
       <div class="card D3"></div>
       -->
                            <div class="card" ng-repeat="card in playerCards" ng-class="playerCards[$index]"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
       <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm btn-group-justified">
        <a class="btn btn-default hit" ng-class="{'disabled':!(enableButtons)}" ng-click="hitButton()">Hit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default stick" ng-class="{'disabled':!(enableButtons)}" ng-click="stickButton()">Stick</a>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You put everything in the controller. That is not god. At the very least make factory with the game logic, that you use in your controller. Also check out this: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: The indentation is quite messy, not following a consistent logic. Does the code look like this in your editor?

Comment: I can just by looking at the code tell you that their rejection is justified. Its messy and the entire thing can be encapsulated better. I think before you start working with angular or any other library you should definately grasp the basic concepts of coding style and strategies.

Comment: Any good sources for the basic concepts of coding style and strategies?

Comment: @ILIAS The big bad is your html though. Inline scripts, bad indentation, js in the document. I mean programming means attention to detail and that includes indentation etc.

Comment: @ILIAS yes hang on

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns

Comment: Also read on indentation and stuff because that is where you really fail. It can easily be learned : ) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the source. However, the reason they rejected me was not the HTML part because it was given to me like that!! My own code was actually the controller...

Comment: they gave you HTML code that had scripts inside with the function: window.shuffle = function (set)????

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I agree that the code style is not great and there are several design issues here as well. For example, why does the main game object have a `shuffle()` function? The Deck should know how to shuffle itself.

Some of your function names are hard to understand. `calculate()` is kind of meaningless. And when I see `value` and `arr` as variable names, I cringe a bit. Names of things are very important. Your functions are generally too long, too, which is usually a sign that they are trying to do too much or that you have other design issues. Try to make them 5-15 lines, though that is only a rule of thumb.

I would look into design patterns but also at refactoring in general. A long conditionals like `arr[value].slice(1)==='J' || arr[value].slice(1)==='K' || arr[value].slice(1)==='Q'` does not read well and could be its own one-line function instead, like `isSuitCard()`. Or, better yet, what if it was `card.isSuit()`? That would look great, but it would require you to turn this Deck array plus chosen `value` into a proper `Card` object. Maybe that's not such a bad idea?

A good goal is to have code that's pleasant for others to pick up and read, especially those who have never seen it before.

Finally, you haven't written any tests and your code isn't easily testable. Another red flag there. I would suggest looking into test-driven development because the discipline of that approach will make you a better coder faster.

Comment: agree with all of the above. In addition, your comment in all the files needs to be better.  Comment cannot be just like  `//end of calculate'. The people who are reading your code knows the function ended.